# Creating a secure home network - Which firmware should I use and how should I configure my firewall?

Tags: network, firewalls, wifi, wireless, cisco

I am starting to take on more and more enterprise clients while working remotely from my home office.  I have a pretty secure network at the moment, but I have a lot hardware that I am not using and should be.  I am a programmer, not a network specialist, so I would like to reach out and ask for some advice on how to make best use of the hardware I have at hand.

My hardware:
Linksys 17351 
CISCO model 1721 series router with 
CISCO 1 Port 10BT Ethernet WAN Interface card
and the router my internet connection came with, Arris DG860/TG862 with firmware 7.5.63C

I currently have about 5 wireless devices that I use, and they are currently setup via a MAC whitelist.  I use WPA2 TKIP/AES security with WPS disabled.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Beside what you have already done disabling WPS and using whitelisting:

- Use the latest firmware
- Disable TKIP, just use AES.
- Obviously... change default login / wifi credentials. Use a decent password.
- Disable UPnP.
- Firewall policies to DROP, only allowing what you are going to use (80,443,22,53,3389...).
- Limit the amount of DHCP devices, also set them to expire every 24h.

But also remember that securing a home network is not just secure the networking devices. Harden your systems, configure the host-based firewall, always install updates, etc.

Comment: I am using the 'someonewhocares' hosts file, I have set the login and wifi credentials to and alpha numeric special character, non-word - with spaces - WPA2, and I am using just AES.  I also Disabled UPnP, set my firewall policies as suggested, and set DCHP devices to expire every 24 hours.

Comment: I would like to know to the optimal hardware configuration concerning the three routers, and WIC.  Also Should I upgrade to tomato?  I was thinking of disabling the Arris Router's wifi and bridging it with NAT to the Cisco 1721 and using the Linksys for broadcasting two additional isolated APs for guest access, sharing, etc. both with the same security but completely separate from the Cisco router which will serve as my main dev network.

Comment: @boy I can't help you with configuration as I don't have those routers.